# Re-Showing the Scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html

So I managed to hide my scrollbar with

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
   display: none;
}
```

and I cant get it back. I have tried

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
   display: none; 
}
```

but this doesn't work either :(.

Also was wondering if anyone could explain briefly on how to install lionbars as I have tried and nothing happens.

Thanks,
Dom

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: did you try `display:auto`?

Comment: @NatureShade, I am trying to make my scrollbar reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Just realised all I needed to do was

`::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: auto; }`

thanks to @Daniel A. White.

Would anyone be willing to post a brief installation guide in lionbar.js so that it covers the whole page and replaces the current scrollbar?

Thanks